# My accents are not interpreted in my WHERE clause and the UNISTR() function does not work

Tags: php, oracle, where-clause

My query does not return anything when my query contains accents on the WHERE clause

The accents are the cause of the problem and I don't know how to fix it.

I think that the encoding in UTF8 is not done, and the ORACLE UNISTR('') method does not work.

The 2 queries return a result in ORACLE SQL DEVELOPER

This query works :

```sql
$database->Parse("SELECT
            ID_WORKSPACE_USERS,
            LOGIN_WORKSPACE_USERS,
            FONCTION_WORKSPACE_USERS
            FROM WORKSPACE_USERS 
            WHERE FONCTION_WORKSPACE_USERS = UNISTR('Job 1')"
        );
```

This query does not work (I don't have any extra space in my database) :

```sql
$database->Parse("SELECT
            ID_WORKSPACE_USERS,
            LOGIN_WORKSPACE_USERS,
            FONCTION_WORKSPACE_USERS
            FROM WORKSPACE_USERS 
            WHERE FONCTION_WORKSPACE_USERS = UNISTR('Job é')"
        );
```

Comment: What character set/encoding are you using for the PHP side - UTF-8 or something more restricted, which might mean the accent is garbled long before Oracle sees the string value? (You should probably be using a bind variable anyway; but the same issue would still apply.)

Comment: My php.ini contain : default_charset = "utf-8"

Comment: OK, then what NLS_LANG set to in the environment PHP is running in? You could maybe add `putenv("NLS_LANG=AMERICAN_AMERICA.AL32UTF8");` (or some other territory/language; the character set is the important part) before you open the connection. It could be a driver/DB incompatibility but try that first.

Comment: When I retrieve information from the database, my objects hold the accents (the accents are interpreted). But when my server makes a request to the database, the accents are not interpreted.
Should I specify the encoding in the Description field when I connect to the database?

Comment: Did you save the php file as UTF-8?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution, this code allows to query the database using UTF8 encoding

You have to indicate `$character_set = 'AL32UTF8'.`

Also, session_mode can take 3 values :

> 0 : uses the database encoding
>
> 1 : uses the national encoding
>
> 2 : use AL32UTF8 encoding

Personally, I set session_mode to null because setting `$character_set` is enough.

So I removed the UNISTR function from my request, no more need.

```php
$character_set = 'AL32UTF8';
$session_mode = null;

oci_connect($login, $password, $description, $character_set, $session_mode);
```